# Need help joining table without pulling in all the data

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to join three tables but only pull in data from two of them. The third table I just want to reference one column in a case statement.

```
SELECT c.Client_ID,
   c.Last_Name,
   c.First_Name,
   d.Sched_Time,
   CASE
    WHEN d.Eventstatus = 1 THEN d.Time_In
    ELSE NULL
   END AS Time_In,
   CASE 
    WHEN d.Eventstatus = 1 THEN d.Time_Out
    ELSE NULL
   END AS Time_Out,
   CASE
    WHEN d.Eventstatus = 1 THEN (d.Time_Out - d.Time_In) * 60 * 24
    ELSE NULL
   END  AS Mins,
   CASE 
    WHEN d.Eventstatus = 1 THEN (Round(d.Sched_Duration/15,1))
    ELSE NULL
   END AS Units,
   CASE 
    WHEN d.Eventstatus = 1 THEN 'Completed'
    WHEN d.Eventstatus = 10 THEN 'Cancelled: No Show'
    ELSE TO_CHAR(d.Eventstatus)
   END AS Appt_Status,
   CASE 
    WHEN d.SRVID = 37913 THEN 'OASAS - Toxicology Rapid Screen'
    ELSE TO_CHAR(d.SRVID)
   END AS Program,
/* Here is where I want to reference the other table. I want it be WHEN d.Eventstatus = 1 AND cd.customfieldvaule != 'CSE' THEN 'Y' */
   CASE
    WHEN d.Eventstatus = 1 THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
   END AS Billable,
   CASE 
    WHEN d.ProvidersID = 112906 THEN 'Some Name'
    ELSE TO_CHAR(d.ProvidersID)
   END AS Provider,
   CASE 
    WHEN d.Activity_Desc = '<b>OASAS</b>   <i>(Group)</i>' THEN 'WGACS'
    WHEN d.Activity_Desc = '<b>OASAS</b>   <i>(Individual)</i>' THEN 'WGACS'
    ELSE d.Activity_Desc
   END AS Location_ID
FROM Clients c
JOIN DAILY_LOG_DATA d 
ON c.SHISID = d.SHISID
JOIN Client_Custom_Data cd
ON d.SHISID = cd.SHISID
WHERE  d.SRVID IN (37913, 36186, 36185, 36180, 36179, 36168, 36167, 36182, 36181, 36173, 36172, 36177, 36176, 36175, 36174, 36178, 36184, 36183, 36188, 36187)
AND c.Last_Name != 'TEST'
AND d.Sched_Time >= TO_DATE('2020-09-28 01:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS') 
AND d.Sched_Time  < TO_DATE('2020-10-04 12:59:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')
```

The Client_Custom_Data table is the one I where I do not want to pull in all the data. Let me know if I need to explain this a little better.

So when I try to join in the 3rd table I get duplicate rows. This is what I tried.

```
FROM Clients c
JOIN DAILY_LOG_DATA d 
ON c.SHISID = d.SHISID
OUTER Apply 
(SELECT cd.customfieldvalue FROM Client_Custom_Data cd
WHERE d.SHISID = cd.SHISID)
```

But even joining the 3rd table, I am still unsure how to use it in a case statement up above where I want to reference the 3rd table. I want it be WHEN d.Eventstatus = 1 AND cd.customfieldvaule != 'CSE' THEN 'Y

Comment: (1) SQL queries don't start with `FROM`.  They start with `SELECT` (or `WITH`).  (2) You select the columns you want.  If you don't want any columns, don't include them in the `SELECT`.

Comment: I know that, but the code is quite long so I didn't know if I should post the whole thing. I was just showing the `from` portion.

Comment: OK; but, Gordon's (2) does what you asked. Name columns you want, omit the others.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by selecting the values you want or with a sub query like this

```sql
SELECT 
c.*, 
d.*, 
(SELECT case_field FROM Client_Custom_Data cd where d.SHISID = cd.SHISID) as case_field
FROM Clients c
JOIN DAILY_LOG_DATA d 
ON c.SHISID = d.SHISID
```

Comment: Be aware this will only work when `SHISID` is unique within `Client_Custom_Data`.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
FROM Clients c
JOIN DAILY_LOG_DATA d 
ON c.SHISID = d.SHISID
OUTER APPLY 
   ( 
   SELECT case_field  FROM Client_Custom_Data cd 
  where d.SHISID = cd.SHISID
   ) A
```

Comment: If I went this route, would the data be presented at the bottom of the table?